# Problem with re-renders in React with useCallback and useMemo

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've got a fairly simple example of a component (Hello.js) that renders three components, each with a different id (Speaker.js).  I have a `clickFunction` that I pass back from the Speaker.js.  I would think that using React.memo and React.useCallback would stop all three from re-rendering when only one changes, but sadly, you can see from the console.log in Speaker.js, clicking any of the three buttons causes all three to render.

Here is the problem example on stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dmclqm

**Hello.js**

```
import React, { useCallback, useState } from "react";

import Speaker from "./Speaker";

export default () => {
  const speakersArray = [
    { name: "Crockford", id: 101, favorite: true },
    { name: "Gupta", id: 102, favorite: false },
    { name: "Ailes", id: 103, favorite: true },
  ];

  const [speakers, setSpeakers] = useState(speakersArray);

  const clickFunction = useCallback((speakerIdClicked) => {
    var speakersArrayUpdated = speakers.map((rec) => {
      if (rec.id === speakerIdClicked) {
        rec.favorite = !rec.favorite;
      }
      return rec;
    });
    setSpeakers(speakersArrayUpdated);
  },[speakers]);

  return (
    <div>
      {speakers.map((rec) => {
        return (
          <Speaker
            speaker={rec}
            key={rec.id}
            clickFunction={clickFunction}
          ></Speaker>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Speaker.js**

```
import React from "react";

export default React.memo(({ speaker, clickFunction }) => {
  console.log(`speaker ${speaker.id} ${speaker.name} ${speaker.favorite}`);
  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        clickFunction(speaker.id);
      }}
    >
      {speaker.name} {speaker.id} {speaker.favorite === true ? "true" : "false"}
    </button>
  );
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because when you fire `clickFunction` it update speakers wich cause the recreating of this functions, to solve this you need to remove `speakers` from `clickFunction` dependencies and accessing it from `setState` callback.
here the solution :

import React, { useCallback, useState,useEffect } from "react";

```
import Speaker from "./Speaker";

export default () => {
  const [speakers, setSpeakers] = useState([
    { name: "Crockford", id: 101, favorite: true },
    { name: "Gupta", id: 102, favorite: false },
    { name: "Ailes", id: 103, favorite: true },
  ]);

  const clickFunction = useCallback((speakerIdClicked) => {
    setSpeakers(currentState=>currentState.map((rec) => {
      if (rec.id === speakerIdClicked) {
        rec.favorite = !rec.favorite;
       return {...rec};
      }
     return rec
    }));
  },[]);
  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("render")
  })

  return (
    <div>
      {speakers.map((rec) => {
        return (
          <Speaker
            speaker={rec}
            key={rec.id}
            clickFunction={clickFunction}
          ></Speaker>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

and for speaker component:

```
import React from "react";

export default React.memo(({ speaker, clickFunction }) => {
  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        clickFunction(speaker.id);
      }}
    >
      {speaker.name} {speaker.id} {speaker.favorite === true ? "true" : "false"}
    </button>
  );
});
```

Comment: Thanks @adel. Appreciate you taking the extra time to go back and improve the answer. I was struggling with how you made it work the first time, but second was easy since it was just the clickFunction change.

Comment: this was really a leadup to my next question which I couldn't ask until I got this one working.  If you have time to look at it, it's almost identical.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63200464/problem-with-re-rendering-when-passing-a-react-function-with-react-context-api

Answer (score 2):

**Upon further reflection, I think my answer may not be entirely correct: without the `[speakers]` dependency this won't work as intended.**

Two things:

1. <strike>The `[speakers]` dependency passed to `useCallback` causes the function to get recreated every time `speakers` changes, and because the callback itself calls `setSpeakers`, it will get recreated on every render.</strike>
2. If you fix #1, the Speaker components won't re-render at all, because they're receiving the same `speaker` prop. The fact that `speaker.favorite` has changed doesn't trigger a re-render because `speaker` is still the same object. To fix this, have your click function return a copy of `rec` with `favorite` flipped instead of just toggling it in the existing object:

```
import React, { useCallback, useState } from "react";

import Speaker from "./Speaker";

export default () => {
  const speakersArray = [
    { name: "Crockford", id: 101, favorite: true },
    { name: "Gupta", id: 102, favorite: false },
    { name: "Ailes", id: 103, favorite: true },
  ];

  const [speakers, setSpeakers] = useState(speakersArray);

  const clickFunction = useCallback((speakerIdClicked) => {
    var speakersArrayUpdated = speakers.map((rec) => {
      if (rec.id === speakerIdClicked) {
        return { ...rec, favorite: !rec.favorite }; // <= return a copy of rec
      }
      return rec;
    });
    setSpeakers(speakersArrayUpdated);
  }, []); // <= remove speakers dependency

  return (
    <div>
      {speakers.map((rec) => {
        return (
          <Speaker
            speaker={rec}
            key={rec.id}
            clickFunction={clickFunction}
          ></Speaker>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: thanks. big help. I still get the warning which I don't understand:    Line 22:5:  React Hook useCallback has a missing dependency: 'speakers'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
overrideMethod @ react_devtools_backend.js:2273
printWarnings @ webpackHotDevClient.js:138
handleWarnings @ webpackHotDevClient.js:143
push../node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js.connection.onmessage @ webpackHotDevClient.js:210.

Comment: Upon further reflection, I think my answer may not be entirely correct: without the `[speakers]` dependency this won't work as intended.

Comment: check my answer you can access current state from `setState callback` so the `useCallback` doesn't relay on it, which can be removed from dependencies.