# Having React Context in Separate File, Can't Get Component to Not re-render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've got a simple example of React Context that uses useMemo to memoize a function and all child components re-render when any are clicked. I've tried several alternatives (commented out) and none work. Please see code at stackblitz and below.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yo4eth

**Index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Hello from "./Hello";

import { GlobalProvider } from "./GlobalState";

function App() {
  return (
    <GlobalProvider>
      <Hello />
    </GlobalProvider>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**GlobalState.js**

```
import React, {
  createContext,useState,useCallback,useMemo
} from "react";

export const GlobalContext = createContext({});

export const GlobalProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [speakerList, setSpeakerList] = useState([
    { name: "Crockford", id: 101, favorite: true },
    { name: "Gupta", id: 102, favorite: false },
    { name: "Ailes", id: 103, favorite: true },
  ]);

  const clickFunction = useCallback((speakerIdClicked) => {
    setSpeakerList((currentState) => {
      return currentState.map((rec) => {
        if (rec.id === speakerIdClicked) {
          return { ...rec, favorite: !rec.favorite };
        }
        return rec;
      });
    });
  },[]);

  // const provider = useMemo(() => {
  //   return { clickFunction: clickFunction, speakerList: speakerList };
  // }, []);

  //const provider = { clickFunction: clickFunction, speakerList: speakerList };

  const provider = {
    clickFunction: useMemo(() => clickFunction,[]),
    speakerList: speakerList,
  };

  return (
    <GlobalContext.Provider value={provider}>{children}</GlobalContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

**Hello.js**

```
import React, {useContext} from "react";

import Speaker from "./Speaker";

import { GlobalContext } from './GlobalState';

export default () => {
  const { speakerList } = useContext(GlobalContext);

  return (
    <div>
      {speakerList.map((rec) => {
        return <Speaker speaker={rec} key={rec.id}></Speaker>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Speaker.js**

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";

import { GlobalContext } from "./GlobalState";

export default React.memo(({ speaker }) => {
  console.log(`speaker ${speaker.id} ${speaker.name} ${speaker.favorite}`);

  const { clickFunction } = useContext(GlobalContext);

  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          clickFunction(speaker.id);
        }}
      >
        {speaker.name} {speaker.id}{" "}
        {speaker.favorite === true ? "true" : "false"}
      </button>
    </>
  );
});
```

Comment: Both answers involve doing exactly what I’m trying to avoid, and that’s having to pass the function as prop. This example is simplified. Real problem has function nested deeply in component tree.

Comment: You mean you want to access `clickFunction` directly in `Speaker` component?

Comment: Yes.  Is it because speaker list is included in context? If I split out function to separate context, will that help?

Comment: Yes that is what i was going to suggest. See the updated answer and the demo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of problems in your code:

- You already have memoized the `clickFunction` with `useCallback`, no need to use `useMemo` hook.
- You are consuming the `Context` in `Speaker` component. That is what's causing the re-render of all the instances of `Speaker` component.

**Solution:**

Since you don't want to pass `clickFunction` as a prop from `Hello` component to `Speaker` component and want to access `clickFunction` directly in `Speaker` component, you can create a separate `Context` for `clickFunction`.

This will work because extracting `clickFunction` in a separate `Context` will allow `Speaker` component to not consume `GlobalContext`. When any button is clicked, `GlobalContext` will be updated, leading to the re-render of all the components consuming the `GlobalContext`. Since, `Speaker` component is consuming a separate context that is not updated, it will prevent all instances of `Speaker` component from re-rendering when any button is clicked.

#### Demo

```js
const GlobalContext = React.createContext({});

const GlobalProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [speakerList, setSpeakerList] = React.useState([
    { name: "Crockford", id: 101, favorite: true },
    { name: "Gupta", id: 102, favorite: false },
    { name: "Ailes", id: 103, favorite: true }
  ]);

  return (
    <GlobalContext.Provider value={{ speakerList, setSpeakerList }}>
      {children}
    </GlobalContext.Provider>
  );
};

const ClickFuncContext = React.createContext();

const ClickFuncProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const { speakerList, setSpeakerList } = React.useContext(GlobalContext);

  const clickFunction = React.useCallback(speakerIdClicked => {
    setSpeakerList(currentState => {
      return currentState.map(rec => {
        if (rec.id === speakerIdClicked) {
          return { ...rec, favorite: !rec.favorite };
        }
        return rec;
      });
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <ClickFuncContext.Provider value={clickFunction}>
      {children}
    </ClickFuncContext.Provider>
  );
};

const Speaker = React.memo(({ speaker }) => {
  console.log(`speaker ${speaker.id} ${speaker.name} ${speaker.favorite}`);
  const clickFunction = React.useContext(ClickFuncContext)

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          clickFunction(speaker.id);
        }}
      >
        {speaker.name} {speaker.id}{" "}
        {speaker.favorite === true ? "true" : "false"}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
});

function SpeakerList() {
  const { speakerList } = React.useContext(GlobalContext);

  return (
    <div>
      {speakerList.map(rec => {
        return (
          <Speaker speaker={rec} key={rec.id} />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <GlobalProvider>
      <ClickFuncProvider>
        <SpeakerList />
      </ClickFuncProvider>
    </GlobalProvider>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

You can also see this demo on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-p4hsnv?file=Speaker.js)

Comment: Very nice @Yousaf.  Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Yousaf, I'm at it again.  Seems just when I think I get it, I run into the next little issue I can't figure out.  Here is a slightly revised question regarding exporting the value as an attribute instead of directly.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63306911/having-trouble-getting-react-usecallback-working-as-named-export

Comment: Hi, seems like your question has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

this will not work if you access clickFuntion in children from `provider` because every time you updating state, provider Object will be recreated and if you wrap this object in `useMemo`like this:

```
  const provider = useMemo(()=>({
        clickFunction,
        speakerList,
      }),[speakerList])
```

it will be recreated each time `clickFunction` is fired.

instead you need to pass it as prop to the children like this:

```
import React, {useContext} from "react";

import Speaker from "./Speaker";

import { GlobalContext } from './GlobalState';

export default () => {
  const { speakerList,clickFunction } = useContext(GlobalContext);

  return (
    <div>
      {speakerList.map((rec) => {
        return <Speaker speaker={rec} key={rec.id} clickFunction={clickFunction }></Speaker>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

and for provider object no need to add `useMemo` to the function `clickFunction` it's already wrapped in `useCallback` equivalent to `useMemo(()=>fn,[])`:

```
  const provider = {
        clickFunction,
        speakerList,
      }
```

and for speaker component you don't need global context :

```
import React from "react";

export default React.memo(({ speaker,clickFunction }) => {
  console.log("render")
  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          clickFunction(speaker.id);
        }}
      >
        {speaker.name} {speaker.id}{" "}
        {speaker.favorite === true ? "true" : "false"}
      </button>
    </>
  );
});
```

Comment: Thanks @adel.  Is this a fundamental issue that context can not be cached to avoid re-renders? I could not find any discussion on this in react docs. In debug tools reason for rerender says “parent component changed”

Comment: Also, this implies there is hope.  Would splitting out function to separate context help?  https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: Hi @Adel, You and Yousaf have been a huge help.   I've run into another small roadblock.  Could you take a look if you have a chance please.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63306911/having-trouble-getting-react-usecallback-working-as-named-export