# Having Trouble Getting React.useCallback working as named export

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In the following code segment, when the value of the context is passed, useCallback keeps all the buttons from re-rendering as expected. That is, `clickFunction` is cached.

Stackblitz:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wnfesi

**clickFunctionContext.js**

```
import { GlobalContext } from "./GlobalState";

export const ClickFuncContext = createContext();

export const ClickFuncProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const { speakerList, setSpeakerList } = useContext(GlobalContext);

  const clickFunction = useCallback(speakerIdClicked => {
    setSpeakerList(currentState => {
      return currentState.map(rec => {
        if (rec.id === speakerIdClicked) {
          return { ...rec, favorite: !rec.favorite };
        }
        return rec;
      });
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <ClickFuncContext.Provider value={clickFunction}>
      {children}
    </ClickFuncContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

That is to say, when I reference this context from the file below, Only the button I click gets rendered and not the others.

**Speaker.js**

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";

import { ClickFuncContext } from "./clickFunctionContext";

export default React.memo(({ speaker, clickFunction }) => {
  console.log(`speaker ${speaker.id} ${speaker.name} ${speaker.favorite}`);
  const clickFunction = useContext(ClickFuncContext)

  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          clickFunction(speaker.id);
        }}
      >
        {speaker.name} {speaker.id}{" "}
        {speaker.favorite === true ? "true" : "false"}
      </button>
    </>
  );
});
```

However, What I need is to return the clickFunction from useContext as a attribute and not the value.

So, I need to change this line:

`const clickFunction = useContext(ClickFuncContext)`

To:

`const { clickFunction } = useContext(ClickFuncContext)`

And, in the `clickFunctionContext.js` I change this line:

`<ClickFuncContext.Provider value={{clickFunction}}>`

To:

`<ClickFuncContext.Provider value={clickFunction}>`

The app works, but all buttons re-render as if I'd not done the callback.

Appreciate understanding why this doesn't work the same as without the extra reference.

Here is the broken stackblitz:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-b6jrt8

---

This is the solution in stackblitz as answered below. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pdglx5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
value={{clickFunction}}
```

This will create a new object, with a clickFunction property. Since it's a new object, it's always going to be different from one render to the next, so react is forced to notify all consumers of the context. The clickFunction may be the same, but the object is not, and react only does a `===` comparison.

If you need to have an object for your context value, you should memoize that object so that it doesn't change until it needs to.

```
const value = useMemo(() => {
  return { clickFunction };
}, [clickFunction]);

// ...
<ClickFuncContext.Provider value={value}/>
```

You can see more on this topic in [react's documentation for context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#caveats)

Comment: Thanks @NicholasTower.   I'm not following why you have the dependency array as not [] to make it just render once.  When I make it [] I get the behavior I want but not quite getting why.

Comment: Because if clickFunction changes, you need the object to change or the code will not work correctly. At the moment, there doesn't appear to be a way for clickFunction to change, so no extra renders will occur. But i'd still recommend writing the dependency array correctly to begin with, so that you can make future changes without breaking it.

Answer (score 1):

hello i don't know why you returning a function and passing it as object in props instead if you want to do that just use `useMemo` instead of `useCallback` like this :

```
const clickFunction = useMemo(
  () => ({
    clickFunction: function(speakerIdClicked) {
      setSpeakerList(currentState => {
        return currentState.map(rec => {
          if (rec.id === speakerIdClicked) {
            return { ...rec, favorite: !rec.favorite };
          }
          return rec;
        });
      });
    }
  }),
  []
);
```